# How to create new logical volume by taking the space from an existing one

Tags: linux, unix, lvm

I am new to the world of logical volumes. I have installed a Linux (CentOS), and the installer created an 50 GB root logical volume (mounted at /), and a 475 GB home logical volume (mounted under /home). There is also 32 GB swap. The hard disk is a hardware-raid-virtual-disk (I don't know if this is relevant)

Now it turned out that I need a large space under /opt, but most of my free space is under /home. I guess the solution must be to create a new opt volume (the space, 200GB should be taken away from the home volume), and mount it under /opt.

It should be easy, but all the tutorials/questions I found deal with setting up LVM from the ground up (which I don't need)... So what is the command to take away a given space from an existing volume, and give it to a new volume? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First unmount /home

```
umount /home
```

Then do a fsck

```
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg-lvhome
```

Now shrink it to 275G

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg-lvhome 275G
```

Resize LV

```
lvreduce -L 275G /dev/mapper/vg-lvhome
```

Mount /home

```
mount /home
```

**NOTE: Of course you need to have 275G free space on /home**

Now you can extend your lv as you like

```
lvextend -L +200G /dev/mapper/vg-lvopt
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg-lvopt
```

Comment: This worked file until the last step, then lvextend gave me the message Logical volume lv_opt not found

Comment: OK, I solved, with lvcreate instead of lvextend and  mkfs.ext4 instead of resize2fs. Thank you very nuch!